# Regex test in JavaScript if a string contains only unique characters

Tags: javascript, regex

A string contains only `[A-Za-z0-9]` characters. I need to know if the tested string contains at least one repeating character.

The following should return false:

```
abc1
abc
```

The following should return true:

```
abc11
1abc1
aabc1
```

abca

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use regex with a [positive look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

```
/(?=^[A-Za-z0-9]+$)(.)+.*\1.*/
```

---

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/pF6aD8/3)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks for help! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this regex for checking whether the characters are unique in the string

```
var str = 'aabbcc';
var isRepeat = (/([a-zA-Z0-9]).*?\1/).test(str); //Checks for repeated character in string
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with:

```
^.*?(\w)\1.*?$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wJ7aZ1/1) (actually, fo**ll**owing matches as well).

---

#### Explanation:

If you don't mind that the character class `[A-Za-z0-9]` can contain `_` as well, `\w` is a shortcut for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Afterwards, the whole expression is bound to the start (`^`)  and end (`$`) of a line/string. Last but not least, the lazy `.*?` matches anything before and after, the `(\w)\1` at least one repeating character.

If you **do** mind about the `_`, leave it as `[A-Za-z0-9]`:

```
^.*?([A-Za-z0-9])\1.*?$
```

#### Hint:

Thinking about it, I have misread your question. This approach will match words like `aabc` or `abbc` but not `1abc1` as required in your question. Use a positive lookahead for this as proposed by @Pranav. Although this does not answer the question someone might be interested in this very solution so I tend to leave the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jan I didn't pay attention to question closely. So @Pranav answer is working and is accepted but it has multiple unnecessary greedy dots. I'll reduce it to:

```
/(?=^[a-z0-9]+$)(.)+?.*\1/im
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/bX0eA4/1)**

Answer (score 1):

If you find the character set restriction too limiting, use this:

```
function isNotUnique(inputString) {
    return !(inputString === [...new Set(inputString)].join(''));
}
```

It doesn't use regular expressions, but, handles most/all? characters as it relies on `Set` to enforce uniqueness. Example with Unicode:

```
let inputs = ['abc1', 'abc', 'abc11', '1abc1', 'aabc1', '☃☃', '☃', '☃abc', '(ฺ◣д◢)ฺ', '(ฺ◣д◢)'];
inputs.forEach(v => console.log(v + ': ' + isNotUnique(v)));
```

Outputs:

```
abc1: false
abc: false
abc11: true
1abc1: true
aabc1: true
☃☃: true
☃: false
☃abc: false
(ฺ◣д◢)ฺ: true
(ฺ◣д◢): false
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just [`.*?(.).*?\1.*`](https://regex101.com/r/sS1wG6/1) if you know already is `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

For only check if matches [`(.).*?\1`](https://regex101.com/r/sI0gP6/1)